# PostgreSQL:table name specified more than once

Tags: postgresql

The following code is working properly on SQL server. But when I try it on Postgres it gives me an error: table name "security" specified more than once

I tried alias but it didn't help. Can any body help?

```
UPDATE security 
SET 
security.review_required_flag = True, 
security.issuer_id = sag_diff."ISSUER_ID", 
security.business_line = sag_diff."BUSINESS_LINE", 
security.cusip = sag_diff."CUSIP", 

FROM security 
INNER JOIN sag_diff 
ON (security.product_id = sag_diff."PRODUCT_ID") 
AND(security.msd_id = sag_diff."MSD_ID") 
AND(security.osp = sag_diff."OSP") 
WHERE security.issuer_id <> sag_diff."ISSUER_ID" 
OR security.business_line <> sag_diff."BUSINESS_LINE" 
OR security.cusip <> sag_diff."CUSIP" 
OR security.industry_sector <> sag_diff."INDUSTRY_SECTOR"
```

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres if you want to use the updated table in the FROM clause you should give them different aliases. In your case however you just need only the second table in the FROM clause:

```
UPDATE security 
SET 
    review_required_flag = True, 
    issuer_id = sag_diff."ISSUER_ID", 
    business_line = sag_diff."BUSINESS_LINE", 
    cusip = sag_diff."CUSIP"
FROM sag_diff 
WHERE security.product_id = sag_diff."PRODUCT_ID"
AND security.msd_id = sag_diff."MSD_ID"
AND security.osp = sag_diff."OSP"
AND (security.issuer_id <> sag_diff."ISSUER_ID" 
    OR security.business_line <> sag_diff."BUSINESS_LINE" 
    OR security.cusip <> sag_diff."CUSIP" 
    OR security.industry_sector <> sag_diff."INDUSTRY_SECTOR")
```

Comment: What happened to the inner join? Does it work without that?

Comment: In fact this is a join based on the conditions in the WHERE clause. You just do not have to use the main table twice.

Comment: particularly thanks for this line "In Postgres if you want to use the updated table in the FROM clause you should give them different aliases".